# Nobody's perfect but I could stand corrected

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, sentence

Is the phrase:

> Nobody's perfect but I could stand corrected...

proper grammar?

I want to say:

> No one is perfect, but if they or I make a mistake, I can take it if they tell me I am wrong.

Are there different or better ways of saying this?

Comment: _I could be wrong but...._

Comment: It's proper grammar, but [stand corrected](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/search/learner-english/direct/?q=stand+corrected) doesn't mean what you want it to. What your first sentence means is *"nobody's perfect, but I might be wrong about that"*. Which is a very strange thing to say.

Comment: If you start by admitting nobody's perfect, you are including yourself in that category, the conjunction "but" seems to contradict your earlier affirmation. Normally *but* is used for contrast purposes: e.g. "Nobody's perfect except for me"; "Nobody's perfect but me"; "Nobody's perfect but I could be wrong". The last sentence means: Maybe there is somebody who is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You might say:

- "Nobody is perfect and I don't mind being told I'm wrong."  or
- "Nobody is perfect and I can stand criticism perfectly."

Answer (score 1):

It sounds here like your intent is to open yourself up for feedback or correction from others, so in this case I think a different conjunction might better express your sentiment:

- "No one is perfect, so I don't mind being corrected."
- "I don't mind being told I'm wrong, since nobody's perfect."

Answer (score 0):

“Nobody's perfect but I could stand corrected” is unusual phrasing, but grammatically correct.   As an advantage, it is slightly humorous, in that it plays off of the common phrases “I stand corrected” (which means “I agree I was wrong, and you have corrected my mistake”) and “I can stand ...” (which means “I can tolerate ...”)

In sum, the “nobody's perfect” part implies “I think I'm right, but I could be wrong”.  The “but I could stand corrected” part implies “and if I was wrong, then I'll agree I was wrong, and that you have corrected my mistake”.